# How to create graph from log item in zabbix?

Tags: zabbix

Say I have log item which collects following logs:

[2014-09-01 23:11:34] [message handled] 23s
[2014-09-01 23:16:27] [message handled] 41s
...

I want to create graph with information about message processing duration.

I can create calculated item from log item,

but how to convert [message handled] 23s to 23, cause regex return only 1 or 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to create another log[] item which extracts "23" from "[message handled] 23s" using its regular expression (see [item documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent)). At this point, however, you will hit [ZBX-7821](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-7821), which says that one cannot set log[] item type to numeric. However, you can proceed by creating a calculated item as you already do that simply returns `last("log[...]")` and graph that instead.